Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{1+ \frac{x}{\sqrt{n}} e^{-x/n}}{(x+1)^2} \hspace{0.1cm} dx$
Evaluate
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{1+ \frac{x}{\sqrt{n}} e^{-x/n}}{(x+1)^2} \hspace{0.1cm} dx$$
As this is a limit of integrals, surely we will be using a (monotone/dominated/bounded) convergence theorem. Monotone convergence cannot be utilized here as it is not true that $f_n \nearrow f$ where $f_n$ is the above integrand (in fact, the sequence of $f_n$ is decreasing!). But we do note that each $f_n$ is bounded. Observe:
\begin{align}
|f_n| &= \frac{ \left| 1+ \frac{x}{\sqrt{n}} e^{-x/n} \right|}{\left|(x+1)^2\right|} \\ 
&\leq \frac{ 1+ \frac{|x|}{\sqrt{n}} e^{-x/n}}{(x+1)^2} \\
&= \frac{ 1+ \frac{|x|}{\sqrt{n}}}{(x+1)^2 e^{x/n}} \\
&= \frac{ 1+ \frac{|x|}{\sqrt{n}}}{(x+1)^2} \\ 
\end{align}
And now I fall short. I observe that for each $n$, $\sup\{f_n(x): x \in (0, \infty)\} = f_n(0) = 1$; that is to say, $f_n$ takes on its largest value at $x=0$ and decreases thereafter. How can I take this observation and manipulate $f_n$ to get this upper bound?

Notice that this integral has a maximum value around $n=14.4$ and an inflection point around $n=31.5$ ($n$ does not need to be an integer). Nice problem !

Here is another solution:
Note that $f(t) := te^{-t^2}$ is non-negative and bounded for $t \geq 0$. We can even show that $C = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2e}}$ is the sharpest bound, although this explicit value is not important in our argument. Then
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}e^{-x/n}}{(1+x)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}f(\sqrt{x/n})}{(1+x)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x.
$$
Since the integrand is dominated by the integrable function $\frac{C\sqrt{x}}{(1+x)^2}$, it follows that
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}e^{-x/n}}{(1+x)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}f(\sqrt{x/n})}{(1+x)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}f(0)}{(1+x)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x
= 0.
$$

Clear and concise result! And clever! I think the variable substitution was necessary to prevent this problem from becoming a painful chore

@GrigorHakobyan, Glad it helped! :)

We have
$$
    \int_0^\infty \dfrac{1}{(x + 1)^2}dx = 1 \tag{0}
$$
and
$$
    0 \le \int_0^\infty \dfrac{xe^{-x/n}}{\sqrt{n}(x + 1)^2}dx \le \int_0^\infty \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{n}(1 + \frac{x}{n})(1 + x)^2}dx \tag{1}
$$
Here, I use the inequality $e^x \ge 1 + x \ \forall x > 0$.
Now, for $n > 1$, you can check that
$$
    \int_0^\infty \dfrac{x}{(1 + \frac{x}{n})(1 + x)^2}dx = \left(\dfrac{n}{n - 1}\right)^2\left(\ln n - 1 + \dfrac{1}{n}\right) \tag{2}
$$
Thus,
$$
    0 \le \int_0^\infty \dfrac{xe^{-x/n}}{\sqrt{n}(x + 1)^2}dx \le \left(\dfrac{n}{n - 1}\right)^2\left(\ln n - 1 + \dfrac{1}{n}\right) \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \rightarrow 0 \tag{3}
$$
Therefore,
$$
    \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^\infty \dfrac{1 + \frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}e^{-\frac{x}{n}}}{(x + 1)^2}dx = 1 \tag{4}
$$

Thanks for the response. I'm wondering how you used the fact that $e^x \geq 1+x$?

@GrigorHakobyan This inequality implies that $e^{-x/n} \le \dfrac{1}{1 + x/n}$

Too long for a comment
It seems that we cannot simply drop the exponent while finding the dominating integrable function. But the integration by parts can help.
$$I(n)=\int_0^\infty \frac{1+ \frac{x}{\sqrt{n}} e^{-x/n}}{(x+1)^2}dx=-\frac{1+ \frac{x}{\sqrt{n}} e^{-x/n}}{x+1}\,\bigg|_0^\infty+\frac1{\sqrt n}\int_0^\infty \frac{(1-\frac xn) e^{-x/n}}{x+1}dx$$
$$\overset{x=nt}{=}1+\sqrt n\int_0^\infty \frac{(1-t)\, e^{-t}}{1+nt}dt=1+\sqrt n\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{1+nt}dt-\sqrt n\int_0^\infty \frac{t\,e^{-t}}{1+nt}dt$$
The last integral is bounded
$$\sqrt n\int_0^\infty \frac{t\,e^{-t}}{1+nt}dt<\sqrt n\int_0^\infty \frac{t\,e^{-t}}{nt}dt=\frac1{\sqrt n}$$
The second integral we integrate by parts one more time
$$\sqrt n\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{1+nt}dt=\frac1{\sqrt n}\ln(1+nt)\,e^{-t}\,\bigg|_0^\infty+\frac1{\sqrt n}\int_0^\infty\ln(1+nt)\,e^{-t}dt$$
$$=\frac{\ln n}n\int_0^\infty e^{-t}dt+\frac1{\sqrt n}\int_0^\infty\ln\big(t+\frac1n\big)\,e^{-t}dt$$
$$=\frac{\ln n}{n}+\frac{e^{1/n}}{\sqrt n}\int_{1/n}^\infty\ln x\,e^{-x}\,dx$$
For $n>1$
$$\big|\int_{1/n}^\infty\ln x\,e^{-x}\,dx\big|<\int_1^\infty\ln x\,e^{-x}\,dx-\int_0^1\ln x\,e^{-x}\,dx$$
therefore,
$$\sqrt n\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{1+nt}dt<\frac{\ln n}{n}+\frac{e^{1/n}}{\sqrt n}\Big(\int_1^\infty\ln x\,e^{-x}\,dx-\int_0^1\ln x\,e^{-x}\,dx\Big)$$
The limit follows.

Trying to go beyond the limit, using $x=t-1$
$$\int \frac{x}{(x+1)^2} \, e^{-\frac{x}{n}}\, dx=\int\frac{e^{-\frac{t-1}{n}}}{t}\,dt-\int\frac{e^{-\frac{t-1}{n}}}{t^2}\,dt=I_1-I_2$$ Using the exponential integral function
$$I_1=\int\frac{e^{-\frac{t-1}{n}}}{t}\,dt=e^{\frac{1}{n}}\,
   \text{Ei}\left(-\frac{t}{n}\right)$$ For  $I_2$, after one integration by parts,
$$I_2=\int\frac{e^{-\frac{t-1}{n}}}{t^2}\,dt=-\frac{e^{\frac{1-t}{n}}}{t}-\frac 1n \, e^{\frac{1}{n}}\,\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{t}{n}\right)$$
Back to $x$ and using the bounds
$$J_n=\int_0^\infty\frac{1+\frac{x }{\sqrt{n}}e^{-\frac{x}{n}}}{(x+1)^2}=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{n+1}{n^{3/2}}\,e^{\frac{1}{n}}\,
   \text{Ei}\left(-\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
Using the asymptotic
$$\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{1}{n}\right)=\gamma -\log
   (n)-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{4n^2}-\frac{1}{18 n^3}+\frac{1}{96
   n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$ Combining all the above
$$\color{blue}{J_n=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\Bigg((\log (n)-\gamma -1)+\frac{2 \log (n)-2
   \gamma +1}{n} +O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \Bigg)}$$ This is a very good approximation; for $n=30$, the relative error is  $0.09$%.
Edit
Writing
$$J_n=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {a_k}{k!\, \,n^k}$$ we have
$$a_k=(k+1) (\log (n)-\gamma )+b_k$$ the first $b_k$ being
$$\left\{-1,1,\frac{7}{2},\frac{19}{3},\frac{113}{12},\frac{127}{10},\frac{323}{20},\frac{691}{35},\frac{6569}{280},\frac{6877}{252},\frac{78671}{2520}\right\}$$
